# Why memcmp return int

Tags: c, integer, manpage, size-t, memcmp

I read about int vs size_t vs ssize_t , and I understand that int and ssize_t is signed while size_t is unsigned.

Why `memcmp` return int and no return ssize_t like `recv` return ssize_t?

Comment: There is no type `ssize_t` in standard C. It's a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` is sufficient to hold the return value of `memcmp`.

The `memcmp` function returns 0 if the two given memory regions are equal, a value less than 0 if the first region compares less, and a value greater than 0 if the first region compares more.

A `ssize_t` may be larger than an `int` (and on most implementations it will be), and an `int` is typically the "natural" word size, so there is no benefit to using the larger size.

Comment: So we will use int when to small signed number . ssize_t to bigger  signed numbers.  unsigned int  to small unsigned number  And size_t to bigger unsigned number?

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom `size_t` and `ssize_t` are typically used when the value represents the length of a memory buffer.  There are other types that can be used for larger or smaller values.  In general, `int` should be used unless there's a reason to do so otherwise.

Comment: Additionally, `ssize_t` is a POSIX data type, not a standard C data type.  The standard version of `memcmp()` could not, therefore, return `ssize_t`.